# user interface for operating system

Tags: user-interface, operating-system

Does anyone knows what is the course of action (at least in general) needs to be taken in order to create your own graphical user interface for operating system(Linux) that has only command line ?

Comment: Related: https://wiki.osdev.org/Graphics_stack

Comment: thanks, btw - do you have something more technical ?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System